# Check if a value exists in a result_array()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following query ....

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM crescent.main_stock where transaction_type like '%Receive%' LIMIT 0,1;";
        $query = $this->db->query($query);
        $result = $query->result_array();
        if (in_array('Receive', $result)) {
            echo 'this array contains Receive';
        }
```

I am trying to check  if a value Receive exists inside the  result_array(), What is the  best way to implement this? Which function should I use to check ?

Comment: What for? That's what the `LIKE` clause already did.

Comment: It actually might not, this would match also "sdgsdgsadgaReceivesafafasgh" for example

Comment: Why don't you just use `=` and exact value instead of like?

Comment: I don't understand @user689017. Are you looking for 'Reiceve' in any field of your query or only in transaction_type ?

Comment: I think it would be better if you could edit this to tell us what you're trying to accomplish if the case is true. You're querying for `LIKE %Receive%` yet it seems you're actually _looking_ for `Receive%`, or perhaps just ` = Receive` - the difference in how you're querying vs. what you're actually doing with the results is a source of confusion for us that you need to address.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if your query returned a value in the form of an array, you can put this at the end of your function:

```
$result = $query->result_array();
print_r($result);
```